# Which is best between try catch and if statement

Tags: java

First of all, I want to describe that there are more than five thousand records. Please let me know the best method for best performance from the following:

```
String hmVALUE = "";

try
{
hmVALUE = hashmapRECORDS.get(key).toString();
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
hmVALUE = "";
}

// Second method:

String hmVALUE = "";

if(Module.hmQUEUED_REQUESTS.containsKey(key))
{
hmVALUE = hashmapRECORDS.get(key).toString();
}
else
{
hmVALUE = "";
}
```

I am using try-catch and want to know which method is best.

Comment: Principle: never use exceptions for normal control flow if you can get around them (there may be exceptional cases but they are rare). That being said, use the third method: `Object x = hashmapRECORDS.get(key); hmVALUE = x != null ? x.toString() : "";`

Comment: Hi and welcome to stack overflow, could you please format your code to make it a bit more readable?

Comment: an if statement is not an alternative to a try-catch. an if statement is about a conditional choice, try catch is exception/error handling

Comment: Btw, your second method would not work as your checking for the key in a map different to the one you're trying to get the value from.

Comment: lot of thanks, now cleared

Answer (score 1):

Neither is ideal. Better to call `get()` and check if the result is null:

```
String hmVALUE = "";
Object value = hashmapRECORDS.get(key);
if (value != null) {
    hmVALUE = value.toString();
}
```

Comment: If it was, OP's second method would be broken.

Comment: I'm assuming OP adapted his code and forgot to update that line.

Comment: Anything's possible, but I can't remember the last time I used a map with null values.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, exceptions are much heavier operations for Java to generate (they need to collect stack traces, etc...) so in this specific case, I would say that if-statement is much better than try-catch.

However, for the question in general, those are completely different mechanisms - the 1st one should handle an unexpected error, while the other one is flow control.

Moreover, you can use the short `condition ? if true : if false` syntax and have the entire code like this:

```
String hmVALUE = Module.hmQUEUED_REQUESTS.containsKey(key) ? hashmapRECORDS.get(key).toString() : ""
```

And more specifically in your case, you can just use the `getOrDefault()` method:

```
String hmVALUE = hashmapRECORDS.getOrDefault(key, "");
```

Comment: I would not use the `containsKey(key)` + `get(key)` combo as this is doing 2 lookups. If don't really have to know whether the key is in the map, i.e. all you care about is the value, just do `get(key)` and check if you got anything: yes - the key is in the map, no - the key might be in the map or not, in any case there's no value for it.

Comment: I wouldn't use it as well, I just copied the code they wrote, this is why I suggested here using getOrDefault() as it will give the same behavior and be easier to understand

Comment: 1) stack traces are only created if/when needed; 2) it actually depends on the data, if we almost always have a hit, the exception is almost not thrown (and *cheaper* than 2 lookup)

Comment: Yeah, that's true, there's no silver built here, and it depends on the case...

Comment: @user3591863 can you accept the answer unless you have anything else that is missing for you?